# Custom Admin Grid Without Database

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid, grid, web-services

I created a grid in the Magento admin, but the functionality like sort, filter and search doesn't work and that is because I didn't use a database table to get the information. I use a web service that connects with redmine and I get all the information. I reviewed and I founded that the default sort, search and filter of the Magento grid only works with models or collections, but I can't find a way to do the same but with my own collection (in this case the info that I get from the web service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd post this as I feel it contributes, but it does not fully answer your question.

I've recently hacked together something that supports an admin panel grid from a non-database source, however it was not built with web-service calls in mind.

It might be useful for people in the future if they want to embark on this kind of functionality to see what I've done.

https://github.com/convenient/CollectionNoDb

Comment: Maybe you could expand on how you went about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean the approach I took to develop it? Or what the module is actually doing. Because if it's what the module is actually doing I suggest you look at the Readme on the github as well as this file.

https://github.com/convenient/CollectionNoDb/blob/master/lib/Convenient/Data/Collection/NoDb.php

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, it's a mess. As you point out, the Adminhtml grid widget assumes that it is working with a `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` instance, yet this is not enforced in the code:

```
/**
 * set collection object
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Collection $collection
 */
//public function setCollection(Varien_Data_Collection $collection)
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;
}
```

This setter implies that the grid widget is built in a generic way, but there are several assumptions that the `$_collection` object implements several methods from the collection class hierarchy:

- `::_addColumnFilterToCollection()` calls `addFieldToFilter()`
- `::_prepareCollection()` calls `load()`
- `::_preparePage()` calls `setPageSize()` and `setCurPage()`
- `::_exportIterateCollection()` calls `getSize()` and `getLastPageNumber()`
- ...et cetera...

You will need to map your resource set to a `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` instance and each entity to a `Varien_Object` to get this working. The more grid goodies you want to use (e.g. export to CSV), the more work you may need to do.

Comment: Which is why most 3rd parties that need to do exactly this rely on a windowed / iframe approach with an API key.

Comment: Then benmarks you suggest that I need create a table with the web service info and with that create a model and collection for use the grid options like sorting, filter, export to csv, etc?

Comment: @RicardoCortes - It's an option, and maybe a good one if say a 15min delay is okay. You could also wrap the API calls in the various methods of the expected classes. Your call!